# js Template literal in querySelectorAll producing error with checkbox:checked condition

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

This is my third time for this issue today. Everytime someone answers my question, I'm very grateful for the help but the issue partially resolved the easy part. The important part still not producing the desired output.

I've a form with options grouped by the option group name. I'm trying to use template literal to get the optiongroup name in my js code to check if the input checkbox checked or not. Should be easy but I'm unable to succeed in this last part.

My form is typical using svelte and html

```
<form name="optionsform" on:submit|preventDefault={()=>collectoptions(itemid, itemprice, itemname,  itemdescription, variationname, variationprice)}>
    
    {#if option['rules'] == "exactly"}
    {#each option.optiongroupitems as optionitem, index} 
    <li style="list-style : none;">
    <label>
        <input  type="checkbox" class={option.groupheader} bind:group={values.exactly} value={optionitem.name} on:click={()=> Validateexactly(option.rulesnumber.number, option.groupheader, optionitem.name)} >
         {optionitem.name} : {optionitem.price}
    </label>
    </li>
    {/each}
    {/if} 
    <button type="submit" >Add To cart</button>
    </form>
```

validateexactly function :

```
 function Validateexactly(limit, groupheader, name) { 
    let getexactlygroup = `${groupheader}` 
    console.log("this is logging corrertly the option group name :", getexactlygroup)
    
    exactlylimit = limit
    var checks = document.querySelectorAll(".getexactlygroup"); // how do I reference option.groupheader correctly?  
    checks.forEach((item, index)=>{
    
      console.log("showing empty list array ", item) 
    
    })
    
    for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
     checks[i].onclick = selectiveCheck;
    function selectiveCheck (event) {  
     var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll('.getexactlygroup'[type="checkbox"]:checked');//showing errors that selector is invalid selector. 
     if (checkedChecks.length >= exactlylimit + 1){
       return false;
     }
    }
    
    }
```

After few kind people posting their answers, I got this part working:

```
let checks = document.querySelectorAll(`.${getexactlygroup}`);
```

And now I'm able to see in the console.log all my option group input grouped correctly.

The issue that I've trying for the past hour is this line:

```
var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll( `.${getexactlygroup}`.input[type="checkbox"][checked]);
```

I tried the following and I get error that type is not a valid selector, input is not a valid selector. So how, I failed from the previous answers how to use template literal. I read the template literal on MDN, then querySelector section.

```
var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll( `.${getexactlygroup}`.input[type="checkbox"]:[checked]); 

var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll( `.${getexactlygroup}`input[type="checkbox"]:[checked]);

var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll( `.${getexactlygroup}`.input[type="checkbox"][checked]); 
var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll( " `.${getexactlygroup}`.input[type="checkbox"]:[checked]");
```

In MDN, someone wrote that :
Note: Characters that are not part of standard CSS syntax must be escaped using a backslash character. Since JavaScript also uses backslash escaping, be especially careful when writing string literals using these characters. See Escaping special characters for more information.

How do I use the `.${getexactlygroup}`[input type checkbox] : checked in js?
I'm so frustrated and I don't think it is that difficult but I'm unable to figure it out. Any js ninja out there with rock solid js knowledge who can help me?

Comment: almost there, try this: `.${getexactlygroup} .input[type="checkbox"]:checked `

Comment: `\`.${getexactlygroup} input[type="checkbox"]:checked\``? You need to read about how template literal works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: The `\`` is not part of the selector, it's part of the template literal syntax! Use ``document.querySelectorAll(`input.${groupheader}[type="checkbox"]:checked`)``. Or, without template literals, good ol' `document.querySelectorAll("input." + groupheader + "[type="checkbox"]:checked")`

Comment: @Bergi How you managed to show The start of the template literal in the comment ? It always renders to me as the beginning of code

Comment: @dippas `\`\\`\`` renders as `\`` :-) Also you can use multi-backticks for code containing single backticks, e.g. `\`\`x\`y\`\`` -> ``x`y``

Comment: ah right makes sense backslash :) Thanks

Comment: If you tag a question as only `svelte-3` people will probably not see it. Always at the main `svelte` tag.

Comment: As was mentioned by @H.B. if you are using `querySelector` in svelte, there is a good chance you are doing something wrong. You can get references to dom elements using `bind:this` you could have a look at that.  I would also try to step back from your solution and think more in terms of 'state', an idea could be to bind the value of checked boxes to a prop: `bind:group={checked[option.groupHeader}` or some thing.  Currently it is actually very hard to help you fix this problem because there are a lot of variables coming out of nowhere, with no idea how the content of these variables look like

Comment: @StephaneVanraes the idea of bind:group={checked[whatevervariable]} is a good idea. I'll try that. But help me out understanding the checked part. How do you reference the input:checked in the bind:group?

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help. All atempts to use querySelectorAll syntax failed. I tried backslash, double quotation, single...etc. All gave error and didn't  get the checked inputs. I'll have to think about something else. If any of you have some creative solution, please share.

Comment: @H.B. Thank you for pointing out the tag issue. I didn't know that and now I know. Very helpful.

Comment: @Marco I think a discussion about reorganizing your application is beyond the goals of StackOverflow and can become very lengthy, I would recommend other channels like the Svelte Discord server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any query selector in svelte in this case.
I would build a checkbox component like this:

```
<script> 
//there are variables to export
  export let value
  export let group
  export let name
  export id
  export let checked

// this is a function to "catch" your changes if the answer that you expect is equal to value that the user will check

function onChange(event: Event) {
    group = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
  }
  $: checked = (group === value)

</script>


<input type="checkbox" id={id} bind:group={ group } value={ value } name={ name } on:change="{ onChange }" { checked }/>
<slot/>
```

Comment: Very clever solution. I'm not so advanced in svelte so I have few questions for you regarding your soltuion: One is onChange(event: Event)  inside the onChange function.  Two: How to add this component to my form and pass the right value to the component props?

Comment: I'm actually thinking to write the question in a separate question so you can add the solution and it would be available to everyone else. It's informative and elegant. It should be available for everyone to see.

Comment: Deotyma : Please answer this question and provide any additional answer because your solution is elegant and creative that it does deserve a question and answer by itself so the rest of the community benefit from this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72835722/creating-a-component-to-accept-checkbox-configuration-to-add-in-a-form-using-sve

Comment: Thanks for all your compliments. It is only vanilla javascript, that is what I like in Svelte. (event:Event) is only a vanilla javascript event (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp). Normally I use Typescript that's why I wrote "Event " to give a type to my element of "event".