# creating a component to accept checkbox configuration to add in a form using svelte only

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a form with item. Users need to choose options to add to the item.
The option groups similar to this objects of array:

```
let optiongroups = [
       {
        groupname : "exactly1",
        grouplimit : 1,
        id : 123,
        optionitems : [
          {
            name : "One",
            price : 1
          },
          {
            name : "Two",
            price : 2
          },
          {
            name : "Three",
            price : 3
          },
          {
            name : "Four",
            price : 4
          }
        ]

       },
       {
        groupname : "exactly2",
        grouplimit : 2,
        id : 369,
        optionitems : [
          {
            name : "2-One",
            price : 22
          },
          {
            name : "2-Two",
            price : 44
          },
          {
            name : "2-Three",
            price : 66
          },
          {
            name : "2-Four",
            price : 88
          }
        ]

       }]
```

My form is :

```
<form name="optionsform" on:submit|preventDefault={()=>collectoptions(itemid, itemprice, itemname,  itemdescription, variationname, variationprice)}>

  {#each optiongroups as group}
  <div style="margin : 5px; border : solid green;">
  <li style="list-style : none;">
    {group.groupname} - {group.grouplimit}
    {#each group.optionitems as option}

    <li>
      <label>
        <input name={group.groupname}  type="checkbox" bind:group={checkresults} value={option} on:click={handleclick}>
         {option.name} : {option.price}
   </label>
      
    </li>
    {/each}

  </li>
  </div>
  {/each}
<button type="submit" >Add To cart</button>
</form>
```

@Deotyma suggested to build a component -let us call it option component- like this:

```
<script> 
//there are variables to export
  export let value
  export let group
  export let name
  export id
  export let checked

// this is a function to "catch" your changes if the answer that you expect is equal to value that the user will check

function onChange(event: Event) {
    group = (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value;
  }
  $: checked = (group === value)

</script>


<input type="checkbox" id={id} bind:group={ group } value={ value } name={ name } on:change="{ onChange }" { checked }/>
<slot/>
```

My question how to include the component in my form component and how to pass the optiongroups info/parameters to the option component? And considering that I have more than one option group one with limiting number of options by 1 and a separate group with limiting number of 2?

I actually created this question so it is available for others to learn from the idea of the component. I'll invite Deotyma to complete the answer so it is available for others as it is an elegant solution for the checkbox limiting issue. I think it the best solution so far.

Comment: Didn't I already provide a sufficient [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b7645fa6485451f8474044af72dd55d?version=3.48.0) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72810473/546730)? Also, passing properties is fairly basic and people who use Svelte should already know that from the tutorial or the docs.

Comment: Here, in answer, I put a [checkbox] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72794190/js-template-literal-in-queryselectorall-producing-error-with-checkboxchecked-co/72822602#72822602) component, maybe  it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was away. Happy 4th. After playing around with the code provided by many answers, I concluded that the answer by H.B. is the best one.

Not only because it is clear and concise but also organized in the best way possible.

The provided answer also has a repl page for your reference.

The reply answer is [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b7645fa6485451f8474044af72dd55d?version=3.48.0)

And the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808622/limiting-the-number-of-checkbox-in-svelte-form-using-disabled-attribute-with-mor/72810473#72810473)

As H.B. indicated in his answer, the single variable was my mistake.
Instead you need to check state by group as he exlained clearly in his example.

```
checkresults = Object.fromEntries(optiongroups.map(g => [g.groupname, []]));

<input name={group.groupname}  type="checkbox"
       bind:group={checkresults[group.groupname]}
       value={[{ "name" : option.name }, { "price" : option.price }]}
       disabled={
           checkresults[group.groupname].length === group.grouplimit &&
           checkresults[group.groupname].some(x => x[0].name == option.name) == false
       }>
```

I personally ended up with the second solution which was even better than what I was trying to do. Having a separate component allows freedom to do whatever you want inside the component and include it in another component with no concern or worry about state.

The separate component is [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b7645fa6485451f8474044af72dd55d?version=3.48.0)

Thank you H.B. again for your help. Happy 4th if you live in the US.